# Can you build Rust for old (Redhat 5 vintage) Linux?

Tags: rust, anaconda, conda

Redhat 5 has the required 2.6.18 kernel but not the latest glibc, g++ and certainly no clang. The binary distribution doesn't run, complaining about glibc version.

Has anyone made an attempt to back port to old Linux? I could imagine cobbling together a frankensystem with an old kernel but new compilers and try to compile against old glibc or statically compile in some of new glibc but it seems like a fraught course.

Just wondering if anyone has tried and can offer guidance?

I'm thinking there must be a distro setup to do such builds. Anaconda, for example, includes lots of new technologies but works fine on Redhat 5. I wonder how they build it?

Update: Once you get some newer compilers working on RHEL5 it's still not possible to build Rust because it depends on a working binary of itself to bootstrap. See: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/9545#issuecomment-54865031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this very issue this weekend, because [Skylight](http://skylight.io) supports Linux 2.6.18, including CentOS 5.10, and we use Rust in our agent.

Alex Crichton of the Rust core team was kind enough to [get this working again](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/ba0c100f3b544a03f4b0d9f597ad048fbab1b926) by using CentOS 5.10 boxes for the build, which uses glibc 2.5 and Linux 2.6.18.

Answer (score 3):

Anaconda packages are built against CentOS 5 (which is equivalent to Redhat 5). The important thing is to compile against an old enough glibc, as it is strictly forward compatible (as you saw). The version of glibc is typically tied to the version of the distro, so your best bet is to make a VM with CentOS 5 and build on that.

The version of the compiler used is not as important, and in fact in some cases it is necessary to use a newer compiler than the old one that comes with the system to get things to work. I have gcc 4.8 built for CentOS 5 which you can get with conda (`conda install -c asmeurer gcc`).

Comment: Thanks. Your pre-built gcc is very helpful.